# Spark Categorize ordered dataframe values by a condition

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
val userData = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, 0),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 0),
  (5, 3),
  (6, 4)
)).toDF("order_clause", "some_value")

userData.withColumn("passed", when(col("some_value") <= 1.5,1))
        .show()
```

```
+------------+----------+------+
|order_clause|some_value|passed|
+------------+----------+------+
|           1|         0|     1|
|           2|         2|  null|
|           3|         3|  null|
|           4|         0|     1|
|           5|         3|  null|
|           6|         4|  null|
+------------+----------+------+
```

That dataframe is ordered by `order_clause`. When values in `some_value` become smaller than 1.5 I can say one `round` is done.

What I want to do is create column `round` like:

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+
|order_clause|some_value|passed|round|
+------------+----------+------+-----+
|           1|         0|     1|    1|
|           2|         2|  null|    1|
|           3|         3|  null|    1|
|           4|         0|     1|    2|
|           5|         3|  null|    2|
|           6|         4|  null|    2|
+------------+----------+------+-----+
```

Now I could be able to get subsets of rounds in this dataframe. I searched for hints how to do this but have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a rolling sum of the `passed` column. You can do it using a sum window function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = userData.withColumn(
    "passed", 
    when(col("some_value") <= 1.5, 1)
).withColumn(
    "round", 
    sum("passed").over(Window.orderBy("order_clause"))
)

result.show
+------------+----------+------+-----+
|order_clause|some_value|passed|round|
+------------+----------+------+-----+
|           1|         0|     1|    1|
|           2|         2|  null|    1|
|           3|         3|  null|    1|
|           4|         0|     1|    2|
|           5|         3|  null|    2|
|           6|         4|  null|    2|
+------------+----------+------+-----+
```

Or more simply

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = userData.withColumn(
    "round", 
    sum(when(col("some_value") <= 1.5, 1)).over(Window.orderBy("order_clause"))
)
```